# AD home directory not getting created ldap_add()

Tags: php, active-directory

I'm adding users to Active Directory via a php script using ldap_add().

Using ldap_get_entries() I've compared the users that I create with those that were created manually.  I can confirm that the same set of attributes is present in both populations , and that the attribute values that I create are structurally consistent with those created in manually entered users.

The problem is that the user's home directory is not getting created.

The relevant attributes (to my understanding), and values, that I am setting in the ldap_add() call are:

```
$info["homeDrive"] = "H:";
$info["profilePath"] = '\\\\NFSFS\\MembersProfiles$\\joecool';
$info["homeDirectory"] = '\\\\NFSFS\\MembersHome$\\joecool';
$info["scriptpath"] = "members.bat";
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

According to a respondent on [technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/28828e15-7bc5-4b26-b262-9c82c2cd62b2), directory creation "does not happen automatically when you use a script to create the user, even when you assign values to the homeDirectory and profilePath attributes".